# Atmega8 doesn't enter power-down mode on sleep_cpu()

Tags: avr, atmega, sleep

I'm trying to put atmega8a to sleep with this code:

```
cli();
sleep_enable();

// set power down mode - 0.5mkA
MCUCR |= _BV(SM1);
MCUCR &= ~(_BV(SM2)|_BV(SM0));

sei();
// now sleep until INT0 or reset signal
sleep_cpu();
```

However, it seems the processor doesn't actually enter sleep -- the power consumption does not drop significantly.

I thought that may be some peripheral remaining enabled can prevent Atmega from entering sleep, but upon checking AVR datasheet and PM I didn't find any suggestions of this (except that power down can be spoiled by eeprom write, which is the thing I do not do).

Could you suggest where to look further?

Comment: I understand the `avr/sleep.h` documentation correctly, you need to set the sleep mode before `sleep_enable`. Does the reference code work using `set_sleep_mode`?[documentation link](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html)

Comment: MCUCR manipulations should be equivalent to set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN).

Comment: I understand that, however, does the reference code work? Keep in mind that Power Down mode keeps the watchdog interrupt active, this is likely resetting your MCU if you are using an arduino (bootloader initialized WD IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems I was wrong that peripheral doesn't influence power consumption. In my case the problem was enabled uart, disabling it before powerdown actually reduced power consumption significantly.